# Paybox integration expresso

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

I was wondering if anyone out here has tried to integrate paybox as a payment service for expresso store so far? I'm about to start working on the integration but if someone already made an attempt I would like some feedback before starting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One or two people have enquired about it but I haven't seen or heard of any completed gateways for Paybox as of yet.

If you're looking to create your own then feel free to look at [Store Check](https://github.com/expressodev/store_check) to get an idea of how that gateway is put together and integrated as it's own extension. The other gateways that ship with Store will also provide a good starting point so give that a go and contact support@exp-resso.com if you need any tips along the way.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I have done some research so far and made a few steps towards the first gateway though nothing extensive and it still needs more work but so far for the shops we are running it works out fine :-)